# Default exe file icon changing

Tags: icons, autoit

I've read I have to add these lines into my `.au3` file:

```
#Region
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Icon=C:\myicon.ico
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Compression=4
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_Fileversion=1.0
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_Fileversion_AutoIncrement=y
#AutoIt3Wrapper_Run_Obfuscator=y
#EndRegion
```

I've put `myicon.ico` into the `C:\` directory.

Then I right click on my `.au3` file and click `Compile`, everything is fine, but the default icon is still the AutoIT icon.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the things that has bothered me about the compile process for quite a while. It doesn't work if you right click your file and 'Compile'.

You have to go via the Start menu > AutoIt v3 > Compile Script to .exe. Once you select your script,  you will see your settings loaded into the GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch script to execute AutoIt's compilation.

For example:

```
@echo off

set FOLDER_CURRENT=%cd%    

set VERSION=v0.x.x.x
set STATUS=prod
set NAME_PROJECT=nameProject_%VERSION%_%STATUS%
set EXE_OUT=%NAME_PROJECT%.exe

set FOLDER_SRC=%FOLDER_CURRENT%\..\src\
set FOLDER_OUT=%FOLDER_CURRENT%\%VERSION%\%NAME_PROJECT%
set ICON_PATH=%FOLDER_SRC%\images\icon.ico
set AUT2EXE_ARGS=/in "%FOLDER_SRC%\main_script.au3" /out "%FOLDER_OUT%\%EXE_OUT%" /icon "%ICON_PATH%"

echo ----[Compilation with aut2exe]----
aut2exe %AUT2EXE_ARGS%
echo -----------------------------------
```

In this batch script, you can do more things like:

- Create output directory
- Copy all necessary directories and files ressources (images, icon, ...)
- Create another file text
- Zip the output folder in order to make deployement easy
- Push the release on git server